# How do I use regex to split a field value into multiple values using two different delimiters

Tags: regex, kql, azure-sentinel

I have a log source in Sentinel that delimits data in two different ways in the same log, e.g. `-` and `$60.

So far I've tried:

```
| extend FieldNameSplit = split(FieldName , '-|$60')
```

As well as:

```
| extend FieldNameSplit = split(FieldName, '-')
| extend FieldNameSplitTwo = split(FieldNameSplit, '$60')
```

Neither of these method have proven effective. Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance for the insight!

Comment: it may help if you could provide a sample record or a few, and the expected output for those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could try using the `extract_all()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/extractallfunction

for example:

```
print input = "a-b-c$60d-e$60f$60g-h"
| extend output= extract_all(@"([^-(\$60)]+)", values)
```

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| a-b-c$60d-e$60f$60g-h | [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" ] |

Comment: That works well for alphabetical characters, but is separating based on 6s and 0s as well. Is there a way to make Sentinel see $60 as a group?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, just to answer my own question, I managed to use replace_regex to make the $60 a -. Happy days! Thanks for the guidance


| extend replaced_input = replace_regex(input, @'$60', @'-')

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I opt to use parse-where in situations like this.